# perform a function in a list in R

Tags: r

I want to perform a function on my list, calculating the returns for my tickers. The aim is to add a column for each ticker in my list.

```
ticker = c("BTC-USD", "^GDAXI")
Stocks = lapply(ticker, getSymbols, source = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)
names(Stocks) = ticker
Return_cal = function(x) {
  x$Return_log = periodReturn(x[,1], period = "daily", type = "log")
}
```

How can I perform the return calculation for each element in my list, having at the end a column for each ticker?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to refer to functions with their respective package if they are not in the standard installation of R. For instance, we cannot know what `getSymbols()` does and what its output looks like since we do not know where you got that function from. Same thing for `periodReturn`.

You can indicate the package by either loading it in advance, e.g. `library(mypackage)`, or you can prepend the package to the function call, e.g. `mypackage::funnyfunction()`.

Now, I assume that `getSymbols()` returns a matrix or data frame such that the first column can be used as an argument in `periodReturn(x[,1], ...)`. Then you can apply `periodReturn()` with your desired arguments to each element in `Stocks` as follows:

```
ticker <- c("BTC-USD", "^GDAXI")
Stocks <- lapply(ticker, getSymbols, source = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)
names(Stocks) <- ticker
Return_cal <- function(x) {
  # this only adds the new column to x but the function does not return anything yet:
  x$Return_log <- periodReturn(x[,1], period = "daily", type = "log")
  x # this returns x
}
Stocks <- lapply(Stocks, Return_cal) # apply Return_cal to each element of Stocks
```